# Parar la ejecucion de un bucle

Tags: javascript, php

es un bucle que recorre los checkbox seleccionados..
envia los datos a un php,
unas veces funciona, otras veces unos sí, otros no.
habría alguna forma de parar el bucle hasta recibir la respuesta del PHP????

```
$("#"+ntabla+" tr").find('td:eq(0) input:checkbox:checked' ).each(function () {
   c++; 
   var iden=$(this).attr('id')
    $.get("multiple1.php?horas="+horasx+"&lugar="+lugarx+"&obra="+obrax+"&id="+iden+"&dias="+hh ,function (data) {

      if (data==1){
      //***Continuar con el bucle*******
         }
      });
        
    });
```

Si voy comprobando con un `alert(iden);` despues de:

```
var iden=$(this).attr('id')
```

al parar la ejecución y esperar hasta que aceptamos el mensaje, parece que le dá tiempo al php a hacer su función, y el resultado es correcto.

Gracias de nuevo...

Comment: puedes apoyarte del async await, para que espere la respuesta antes de continuar con el flujo que es lo que deseas.

Answer (score 0):

En respuesta a lo que expones la idea es hacer uso del `async` y `await`.

Te comparto un enlace donde puedes comprender mejor el comportamiento de los `async` y `await` [click aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```js
$("#" + ntabla + " tr").find('td:eq(0) input:checkbox:checked').each(async function() {
  c++;
  var iden = $(this).attr('id')
  await $.get("multiple1.php?horas=" + horasx + "&lugar=" + lugarx + "&obra=" + obrax + "&id=" + iden + "&dias=" + hh, function(data) {

    if (data == 1) {
      //***Continuar con el bucle*******
    }
  });
});
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Con una función de espera...(Sleep), parece que está resuelto el problema..Gracias a todos....